# Angular - Use libraries referenced in another third party library

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple [NG-Admin](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin) project.  I need to make a couple API calls that are not the default functionality of their awesome product.  I see they use Restangular and I'd like to continue using it too.  What is the normal way to reference a library that is included in another third party's library?  I tried:

```
var adminApp = angular
    .module('app', ['ng-admin', 'Restangular'])
    .run(run);
```

But it tells me that I do not have the library.  This means that I would need to include both Restangular and Angular on my index page, where ng-admin also includes them.  Am I able to inject or pull a reference from their library to use it?  Or is it fine to also include the libraries?  Will I need to worry about keeping the version the same?

I have seen where you can reference the providers in their [book](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/blob/master/doc/API-mapping.md) to change headers and such, but not to use the methods provided such as 
`Restangular.all('accounts')`.

I'm happy to rtfm, just not sure where to start for this problem.

*I'm still pretty new to Angular, forgive me if this is an overly simplistic question.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-admin` module uses and depends on the `restangular` module, just like you wrote.

If you add `ng-admin` as a dependency, you will get access to `ng-admin` as well as to all its dependencies.

All you should have to do is:

```
var adminApp = angular.module('app', ['ng-admin']);
```

Note that the module is called `restangular`, while the service is called `Restangular`.

From the `restangular` starter guide:

```
// Add Restangular as a dependency to your app
angular.module('your-app', ['restangular']);

// Inject Restangular into your controller
angular.module('your-app').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Restangular) {
  // ...
});
```

So in your case you only need to add `ng-admin` as a module dependency, then inject the `Restangular` service in for example your controller to use it.

Comment: Great, thanks for the detailed explanation!  If I could pretend the front end didn't exist I'd be in one happy bubble.